# Django Pagination KeyError 'source'

Tags: python, django, pagination

I installed Django template pagination tag from: https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination and while I followed all the instructions, I'm getting 'source' errors.

Apparently I'm doing something wrong.

===========================================

**EDIT 3**

**SETTINGS.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

**VIEW.py:**

```
def pagination(request):
location = Location.objects.all()
return render_to_response('pagination.html',
                      location,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
{% load bootstrap_pagination %}

<h1>Location</h1>
{% for location in location %}
<h2>{{ location.name }}</h2>
{% endfor %}

{% bootstrap_paginate location %}
```

**ERROR:**

```
AttributeError at /pagination/

'str' object has no attribute 'paginator'

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/pagination/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'paginator'
```

**Error during template rendering**

```
In template /home/jr/Documents/python/amapp/sdr/article/templates/pagination.html, error     at line 7
'str' object has no attribute 'paginator'
1   {% load bootstrap_pagination %}
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   {% bootstrap_paginate location %}
```

Comment: I had this similar issue, which got resolved. However, I used the default page object in Django `{% bootstrap_paginate page %}`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the library, but you must forgive me as I haven't used Python in quite some time and I've core dumped most of my knowledge about this library.

So, @WayBehind was correct, your first mistake was using "page_obj". That was simply an example. In your case, you want to use "location"

However, you never got to see that error because you have a more pressing error which is that the library isn't playing nice with your setup. I wrote this library with Python 2.7 with the request context preprocessor. Please double check that you have the context preprocessor enabled as per the documentation and please be sure you are using Python <3.0. I know for a fact the library does not currently working on 3.x. There is a fork of the library where some other folks have been working to fix that and I am actively keeping an eye on it to pull those changes in when ready, but as of now it just doesn't work.

If you are using Python 2.x and you have the request context preprocessor enabled, I am not sure why you would be getting that error. If you can confirm those two things are true, I'll be happy to take a closer look tomorrow.

Edit:

This may or may not be an issue, but I notice that you loop through your Location object using the same variable name for the instance:

```
{% for location in location %}
<h2>{{ location.name }}</h2>
{% endfor %}

{% bootstrap_paginate location %}
```

Is it possible that Django's template scoping is such that the object you are passing to bootstra_paginate is the last instance of "location" rather than the entire set? This is an off the cuff guess as a first stab at this because otherwise things appear to be correct.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the feedback. To answer your questions, I do have request context processor enabled and I'm using Python 2.7.I have updated my original post with EDIT3 with my latest version of the view/template/error. I was using standard Django pagination without any issues but I really wanted something better for the URL and bootstrap. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Check my edit and let me know if that works. Shot in the dark, but let's start with the first thing I notice and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all the steps ?

Request is in the context_processor (settings.py)?

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ....
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    ....
)
```

You are using obj_list in the template, but do you have anything inside obj_list ? Maybe you have to use "location" instead of "obj_list"  ? Because I think your object list is inside location (Location objects) but you are using obj_list like in the example. In the example obj_list is just a variable example for an object list.

**EDIT:**
Change this:

```
def pagination(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['location'] = Location.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('pagination.html', args)
```

for this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
    def pagination(request):    
        location = Location.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('pagination.html', 'location':location,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the problem is in the view.py where I have to load the paginator functionality and add also to add some paginator values to the view. What do you think?

Comment: "KeyError at /pagination/: 'request'" It seems that that request 'doesn't exist in the view'. Have you tried to change {% bootstrap_paginate page_obj range=10 %} for {% bootstrap_paginate location range=10 %} ?

Comment: Thanks again for the help! When I run your view above, I get `SyntaxError`. When I remove the `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` part, the view will process but I will get the same `source` error even if I change the `{% bootstrap_paginate location range=10 %}` , which is the part that is triggering the error. Any suggestions? Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: check this documentation [render-to-response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) Because I use context_instance=RequestContext(request) in my views without any syntax error. (have you made this import "from django.template import RequestContext" in your view ? Sorry for this useless help :0 But Anyways I think that your problem is the management of the request, because "KeyError at /pagination/
'request'" if request is working well you won't receive this error.

Comment: Thanks again for your patience! I tried to adjust your view based on the Django tutorial and now I'm not getting view error but I do get `AttributeError at /pagination/
'str' object has no attribute 'paginator'`. I have posted the view and the error above. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: "AttributeError at /pagination/ 'str' object..." This error is in the template ? If Location has the object list as I'm seeing in "location = Location.objects.all()" I don't understand why you get that error. Where exactly do you get this error ? Are you using "return render_to_response('pagination.html', 'location':location..."?

Comment: Yes, the error is in the template and the `{% bootstrap_paginate location %}` is highlighted. I have updated the OP with EDIT 3 that has everyting I'm currently suing. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Using `page_obj` worked for me, for anyone wondering why this doesn't work when using **Django 2.0.2** and **django-bootstrap4 0.0.6**.

I came across this by digging through the context variables in the error message that showed up from Django's DEBUG mode.